# Windows - MINGW Build GSL for Ruby-GSL

Tags: ruby, windows, build, mingw, gsl

Hi I am on windows 7 and wanted to install GSL http://www.gnu.org/software/gsl/ so that I can use it with Ruby GSL http://rb-gsl.rubyforge.org/.

I have MINGW and MSYS installed. I found a binary installer for GSL for version 1.13 here http://ascend4.org/Binary_installer_for_GSL-1.13_on_MinGW but since the latest version is 1.15 released the 6th May 2011 I thought it would be good to build it to install it but I don't how.

Can anyone tell me how to build it so it will install windows?

Comment: Did the "rglpk" example work for you or did you decide to go with Ubuntu on VirtualBox?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I modified the steps for installing the GNU Linear Programming Kit (GLPK) which has also has ruby wrapper, "rglpk".
http://en.wikibooks.org/wiki/GLPK/Ruby

Open

Run
    cd /C/temp/gsl-1.14
    ./configure --enable-shared
    make
    make check
    make install
    cp include/gsl-config /C/Ruby193/include/ruby-1.9.1
    cp src/.libs/libgsl.a /C/Ruby193/lib
    gem install gsl

If that does not work, it might make more sense to install Ubuntu on Virtual Box and build your packages there.

https://www.virtualbox.org/
http://www.ubuntu.com/